# jquery tools hello world template

Tags: jquery-templates, jquery-tools

This is a very promising set of tools, but the very first steps do not seem to be described anywhere. THe forum returns 501 error and there are no ready to launch html templates.

Below is my attempt to get started, but something is wrong, apparently. could you correct it to make it show some basic functionality?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center">

<%-- :mode=jsp: get handle to demo area --%>
<%@ page import="org.flowplayer.demo.*" %>
<c:set var="demoArea" value="${context.toolDemos2}"/>
<% DemoArea area = (DemoArea)pageContext.getAttribute("demoArea"); %>


<style>
#demos {
    background:#fff url(/img/global/gradient/h150_reverse.png) repeat-x scroll 0 -95px;     
    padding:30px 0 30px 40px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

.col {
    margin-right:0;  
    width:280px; 
    border-right:1px dotted #ccc;
    float:left;
}

#col1, #col2 {
    padding-left:30px;      
}

#col2 {
    border-right:0px;       
    width:310px;
}


.cat {
    width:230px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

.cat a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#999; 
    margin:2px 0;
}

.cat a:hover {
    color:#333;
}

.cat h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.combinations h3 {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.col h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.col h2 strong {
    color:#5A57AB;
}

.pic {
    background:url(${cdn}${jqt}/img/jqt_sprite_medium.png) no-repeat 0 10px;
    height:200px;
    margin:-10px 0 -50px;   
}

#pic-form {
    background-position:0 -200px;       
}

#pic-toolbox {
    background-position:0 -400px;
}
</style>


<script>
$("#jqt3").addClass("active");
</script>

<div id="demos">
    <c:forTokens items="ui,form,toolbox" var="main" delims="," varStatus="j">

        <div class="col" id="col${j.index}">

            <h2>${main} ${j.index < 2 ? '<strong>TOOLS</strong>' : ''}</h2>

            <div class="pic" id="pic-${main}"></div>

            <c:forEach items='<%= area.getCategories((String)pageContext.getAttribute("main")) %>' var="cat" varStatus="i">

                <div class="cat ${cat.title == 'Combinations' ? 'combinations' : ''}">
                    <h3 title="${cat.description}">${cat.title}</h3>

                    <c:forEach items="${cat.demos}" var="demo">
                        <a href="${demo.path}">${demo.title}</a>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>

                <c:if test="${i.index == 3}"><br clear="all" /></c:if>

            </c:forEach>

        </div> 

    </c:forTokens>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is no element with `id="jqt3"` and I can't find where you are creating it. Besides I'd suggest trying to add class after DOM is ready `$(document).ready(function(){$("#jqt3").addClass("active");});`

Comment: Following your comments, here's version 2:
http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/Q5nQs/

Comment: Stripped it down to http://jsfiddle.net/EwhzW/ and added jQuery as library in left menu

Comment: Thank you. There is a difference - the button gets surrounded by a red square. it has lost its jquery to it, though. http://www.clipular.com/c?11036009=hlmHoX9oNVlJToneA82BgqvakBg&f=.png
What is the expected effect? As i hover over the button nothing happens...

Comment: I mean could you make the script display a bubble upon hovering over the button? to my eyes, the functionality that this fiddle does not seem to draw on jqtools. Easy to check: when I remove external resources reference to jquery.tools.min.js, the fiddle does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basic example of using jquery-tools tooltips

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>    

<style type='text/css'>
.form {
    margin: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:gray;
    font-size:12px;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#eee;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form input[type="radio"]').tooltip();
});
//]]>  

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" class="form" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="jqt1" value="jqt1" title="Tooltip text 1"><label for="jqt1">label 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="jqt2" value="jqt2" title="Tooltip text 2"><label for="jqt2">label 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="jqt3" value="jqt3" title="Tooltip text 3"><label for="jqt3">label 3</label><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79rHK/

In your fiddles link to jquery tools was broken.

Comment: well, what do you want to work with jquery mobile? jquery.tools.tooltips? How whould you simulate hover on touch-screens?

Comment: you are right. the bubbles would have to be visible all the time.

Comment: As for me it's easier to show them manually than use some specific library

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/search-results.php?search=bubble
there seems to be no bubble functionality in jqm.

it would certainly be better in terms of compatibility not to use external libraries, but I want to add tutorial mode to an app that I am finishing and jqm seems infufficient in visuals.

Comment: you can create such functionality. just look at [jquery.tools.tooltip.js](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js). The main part is [trigger](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L154) which shows or hides tooltip and [show/hide methods](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L186).